# javascript document.getElementById().value

Tags: javascript, html, input

Sorry, I'm newbie,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById('x').value;
var y = document.getElementById('y').value;
var z = x + y;
alert(z);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="number" id="x" />
<input type="number" id="y" />
</body>

</html>
```

If my input x = 100, and y input = 200.
My popup alert are 100200.

How to fixed this?

thank you.

Comment: You need to cast your variable to int...use `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the value is a `string`, you need to convert it to a number and then do the addition.. This should do it..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('x').value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('y').value);
    var z = x + y;
    alert(z);
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="number" id="x" />
    <input type="number" id="y" />
</body>

</html>
```

Function parseInt will convert the string to an integer number and then 100+200 will be 300.

Find the Fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2tk9jdmh/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use

var z = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);

Answer (score 0):

> You need to typecast variables using [`parseInt(var)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) since they are
>   strings.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById('x').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('y').value;
    var z = parseInt(x) + pasreInt(y);
    alert(z);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="number" id="x" />
    <input type="number" id="y" />
</body>

</html>
```